# Dell Switch N3048 with PowerConnect 6248

Tags: switch, vlan, dell

I have two Dell switches and its a classical VLAN Scenario that does not want to work. 
PowerConnect 6248 is connected to the outside world and from there i like to bring new subnet ( this is already done via ISP ) to new infrastructure that is connect to the other switch N3048.

```
ISP =====(port48) PowerConnect (port 11 and 12 as trunk)=====(port 11 and as trunk)N3048====(as access belong to VLAN 25)Servers.
```

So PowerConnect have many VLANs and works excellent, i have create this new VLAN 25 and this trunk ports. Also on port 48 i have enabled/allowed this new VLAN to go out to public. Make port 11 and 12 as trunks.
On the other switch port 11 and 12 are configured as trunks, and 20,21,22,23 are configured as access and assigned to VLAN 25 as it created.

So can somebody give some hints or tell me what is wrong with this scenario that does not work ?

simple configuration that i have on both switches

```
interface ethernet 1/g11
switchport mode trunk

interface ethernet 1/g12
switchport mode trunk

interface Gi1/0/11
switchport mode trunk

interface Gi1/0/12
switchport mode trunk


interface Gi1/0/20,21,22,23 
switchport access VLAN 25
```

Also i have put this servers directly to the PowerConnect and they work excellent, so port 48 and ISP are ok.

Comment: At first sight, you are doing a L2 loop. You should make a Port-channnel to improve performance and reliability. Anyway, it can works with your design (with a path blocked by STP).

Have you defined VLAN 25 in both switches?

A full running-config and a show interfaces would be useful.

Comment: Hi KorXo, Yes it works with disabling the STP on one of the ports i learn that on hard way ... as with Cisco Switches this is done automatically. Any way now one port is working and i need to go with two ports so ill try LAG configuration without STP and see how things will go.